# What is the maximum value that can be generated by 6 random bytes in the crypto module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

If I'm using `parseInt(crypto.randomBytes(6).toString('hex'), 16);`, what's the maximum value I can get?

My ultimate goal is to get a float value out of it (like `Math.random()` ), so I want to divide the result I get from `parseInt(crypto.randomBytes(6).toString('hex'), 16);` by the maximum value.

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF = 281474976710655

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen  Thanks! Could you please elaborate on how to make this calculation?

Comment: Just convert 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF (which is hexadecimal) to decimal.
FF is one byte. so 6 bytes is 6 FF in a row. Convert that to decimal and you get the exact decimal number. You could however just use the hexadecimal value instead of the decimal value since they are the same thing. Just different base.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen  Cannot upvote because I don't have enough reps to do so, but thanks!

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen  now I have enough reps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each byte has a maximum value of 256, so with 6 bytes, the total maximum value is 256^6 - 1 which is 281,474,976,710,655. It's 1 less because you start counting from zero.